# Creating a new distribution profile for an application after deleting it from iPhone?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I created a distribution profile of my application, installed and tested it on my iPhone and uploaded the binary to App Store. Due to some usual reasons Apple rejected it and asked me to make a few changes.

Meanwhile I deleted the application from my iPhone. Now when I reinstall it says valid provisioning profile is not present, so will I have to repeat the whole process of making a distribution profile and then upload it to the store. The provisional profile cannot change, so should I create the new distribution profile with the same one and delete the old distribution profile I made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out *[How to Fix Code Signing Errors](http://www.drobnik.com/touch/2009/05/how-to-fix-code-signing-errors/)*.